# Ubuntu 19.04 Screen Sharing Issues

Tags: remote-desktop, 19.04, tls, vino

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04 on a new computer today. I need to be able to use VNC (Remmina) to remotly connect to this new computer regularly.
I logged on, ran

```
sudo apt install vino
```

and then rebooted and then used my ubuntu 18.10 laptop to try to connect and get a dialog stating:

```
TLS handshake failed: An illegal TLS extension was received..
```

I then confirmed all the settings, and then even went and ran this on the server

```
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

But I still got the same error

Remmina's log window gives me this additional info

```
[VNC]VNC server supports protocol version 3.7 (viewer 3.8)
[VNC]We have 2 security types to read
[VNC]0) Received security type 18
[VNC]Selecting security type 18 (0/2 in the list)
[VNC]1) Received security type 2
[VNC]Selected Security Scheme 18
[VNC]TLS session initialized.
[VNC]TLS anonymous credential created.
[VNC]TLS handshake blocking.
[VNC]TLS handshake failed: An illegal TLS extension was received..
```

I can not for the life of me figure out how to connect to this machine, I primarily use this machine remotly so this is kind of important if anyone knows of a fix. I might try a fresh install even but have a feeling it wouldnt matter as this was litterally the first thing i did

Comment: I have tried a fresh install again with 19.04 and it gave the same errors, then i installed 18.10 instead, and that worked.